# How to retrieve all instance in grails database

Tags: grails

These are my domain class

GameCategory.groovy

```
class GameCategory {
String categoryName
String icon
String toString(){
    "${categoryName}"
}
static hasMany = [ list:GameList]
static constraints = {
}
```

Game.groovy

```
class Game {
String gameTitle
float gamePrice
String gameDescription
Date releaseDate
float rating
int numberOfRaters
int numberOfReviews
String toString(){
    "${gameTitle}"
}
static hasMany = [list : GameList ]

static constraints = {
}
```

GameList.groovy

```
class GameList {
static belongsTo = [game : Game , category : GameCategory]  
static constraints = {
}
```

My question is, how do I retrieve all instance of a game given a category as parameter I'm having trouble understanding the hasMany and belongsTo in grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{it.game}
```

You could make it more complicated by using [createCriteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) but then you have to join with an alias and the code will become more complicated.

Comment: can you please explain what is "it" in it.game and what collect{it.game} do?

Comment: It referrs to the closure argument of collect:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2010/05/groovy-goodness-use-collect-with.html

it might be more clear to write it as 
GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{GameList currentList -> currentList.game}

Comment: So If I want to put all games in a list I just need 
def sampleList = GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{it.game}?

Comment: Ok one last question before I try it out where did you get the "myCategory"?

Comment: myCategory is the GameCategory that you already have and that you want to find all games for.

Comment: If you don't already have a GameCategory instance you might want need to query for it using 
def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(myCategoryNameString)

Comment: I did def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(myCategoryNameString)
then 
def game = GameList.findAllByCategory(myCategory).collect{it.game}
then [game:game]
and in my view I  did <g:each in="${game}" status="i" var="game"> ${game.gameTitle }</g:each>  and It shows nothing but I have two games in that certain category

Comment: nvm I changed var="game" to games and it worked thankss!!